# Java list iterations

Tags: java

```
for (int i =0; i < Entry.size(); i++) {
    if (Math.abs(Entry.contains(Entry[i]-(Entry[i+1])))
```

Given a `list = {4,1,4,2,3}` or whatever the user enters. I essentially want to calculate if the first index 0 subtract the second index 1 is equal to any other value in the list (absolute values). My attempt is above; I thought it would work but it doesn't.

If the list contains the values `4 - 1 = (3), 1 - 4 = (3), 4 - 2 = (2), 2 - 3 = (1)` output some message is essentially what i'm trying to do.

Does anyone know any way of doing this using a list?
I'm new to programming, go easy on me if my mistake is trivial.

Comment: @nullpointer - probably a List variable that has a capitalized name

Comment: My scanner takes in some input and stores it into a list

Comment: So... Do the math... `i-i+1` always equals 1.

Comment: Sorry I changed that. It's the first position in the list subtract the second.

Comment: Still equal to 1.  (Well, -1 now.)

Comment: `i-(i+1) = i - i - 1 = -1` @markspace

Comment: @cricket_007 You're right, apparently I can't do algebra either.

Comment: How would I code it to represent the position, my first thought was something along the lines of: if(Math.abs(Entry.contains(Entry[i] - Entry[i+1])). But that doesn't go well either :D

Comment: OK, and how do you represent `Entity[i]` with a Java list?

Comment: That's my problem, I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `Math.abs` the way you're trying to, nor can you use `i - i + 1` the way you're trying to.  `i - i + 1` is just `1`.

What you *could* do is something like

```
 entry.contains(Math.abs(entry.get(i) - entry.get(i + 1)))
```

...though you also still have to limit how high `i` can go, because `i` can only go as high as the *second* to last entry in the list.  I'll let you work out how to change the for loop to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this shall help you :

```
ArrayList<Integer> entry = new ArrayList<>(); //You might want to use arraylist to help you
entry.add(1);
entry.add(2);
entry.add(3);
for(int i=1;i< entry.size();i++)
    if (entry.contains(Math.abs(entry.get(i)-entry.get(i-1))))
         System.out.println("Got one such element..");
```

Note : `Entry` could be an interface from `java.util.map`. Try using better conventions.

Comment: @cricket_007 : true,modified.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to check every element deducting the next element, you may want to limit your loop with 1 lesser than your list's size, so it won't deduct to last against the next (non existing element) after your last element:

```
for(int x=0; x<list.size()-1; x++)  //iterate first element to 2nd last element
    if (list.contains(Math.abs(list.get(x)-list.get(x+1))))
         //Do whatever you want if such element is found
```

---

```
Entry.contains(Entry[i]-(Entry[i+1])
```

will return you a `boolean` value`(true/false)`.

However, `Math.abs()` is expecting a numeric value (int, long, float or double) as its argument. Your current codes `Math.abs(Entry.contains(Entry[i]-(Entry[i+1]))` will give you an error.

Answer (score 0):

This code might he helpful

```
ArrayList<Integer>  at = new ArrayList<Integer>();// declare your list

at.add(4);
at.add(2);
at.add(1);
at.add(1);
for (int i = 0 ; i <at.size() ; i++) {
    if (i+1 == at.size()) {/// to avoid out ofboundexception
        break;
    }

    if (at.contains(at.get(i)-at.get(i+1))) {// contains the result.
        System.out.println("Success");
    }
}
```

Note: not sure if you want to consider the values being examined for e.g in the above scenario 4 -2 = 2 which is the 2nd element